# Visual Studio 2013 : how to open multiple projects in different windows?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to open two projects in two different windows but every time I double click an other solution, it closes the old project and then it opens the new project in that window. I mean I could do this with VS 2010 but with VS2013, I can't. How do you open multiple projects in different windows ?

EDITS: maybe I can't explain myself well. I want to open two different solutions in two different windows. this will make me able to work on many projects at the same time.

**SOLVED**:This issue disappeared as I reinstalled the OS!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to open each projects source code in a new window? Like open a webpage in a new window? is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes @Jonny I want to do something like a browser ( chrome for example ), when you open a link in a new window.

Answer (score 16):

**For Windows 8:**
you just need to search for Visual Studio in the start menu, then right click and choose Open new window. It will open another instance of Visual Studio.

**For Windows 10 and above:** You need to right click of the Visual Studio on taskbar and click to program name(which is Visual Studio). It will open new instance of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Start visual studio as many times as needed and open each project in each instance of visual studio (file -> Open -> Project/Solution )

Comment: Thank you @Max but it doesn't work. When VStudio is already started, I can't start it once more: when I click nothing works.

Comment: "start menu -> Microsoft visual studio 2013 ->  Visual Studio 2013" does not work ?  You cannot open multiple instances of VS2013? That is weird. what happens when you try to do it? an error/warning message?

Comment: I doesn't work! Nothing happens... Neither error message nor waning. And when I browse to a solution, right-click and Open with VS2013, it closes the former project.

Answer (score 0):

in VS13, when you open source code, it opens it in tabs, you can see the name of the tabs right at the top of the window.(the name of the source code will be there) just drag it and move it off Visual studios, somewhere over your desktop and it will open in a new window. I believe that will work. Please let me know if this works, i know i have documentation on viewing tabs in VS, let me find it while you test this :) 
if you want a way around opening another instance of VS, open the project by locating it For instance C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects thats my default location, open the project there, it opens VS as a new instance

Comment: sorry @Jonny maybe I can't explain myself well. I want to open two different solutions in two different windows. this will make me able to work on many projects at the same time.

Comment: I understand, please go to this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079278/view-more-than-one-project-solution-in-visual-studio
I think that may be what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry but this is not the way my VS2013 works. I can't start many instances of VisualStudio 2013. I think this is an issue with my OS. Thank you for time and effort.

Comment: No, if you want a way around opening another instance of VS, open the project by locating it For instance
C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects
thats my default location, open the project there, it opens VS as a new instance

Comment: Thank you! Please copy the following and edit answer and I will accept it...

SOLUTION :  I associated each `.sln` file to VS2013 and then when I double click a project solution, It then starts a new instance of VS2013.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the problem was solved!

- I have created another user in Windows OS
- Log on with the new user credentials
- Open Visual Studio

The issue remains when I log with another user, that is why I would say it is due to `current user settings`.