# How to launch multiple instances of Visual Studio Community 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have Visual Studio Community 2013 installed on my computer (Windows 8.1).

I would like to run multiple instances of Visual Studio to be able to work on two different solutions (I would like to copy some things from one solution to another).

When one VS instance is open and I try to launch the second one, nothing happens. I didn't find any option in VS configuration that would be responsible for this.

Has anyone a solution for this? Or is it a limitation for Community Edition?

Comment: My installation of Visual Studio Community 2013 (Version 12.031101.00 Update 4) can be started more than once under Windows 7 64 bit. See related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610704/visual-studio-2013-how-to-open-multiple-projects-in-different-windows

Comment: Thanks! I found the solution in reply from Lera from your link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a working solution written by Lera: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27076214/4439713

> If you have Windows 8, you just need to search for Visual Studio in the start menu, then right click and choose Open new window. It will open another instance of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

After opening the Visual Studio ,Mouse Middle click the Visual Studio icon in Task Bar to open another instance of VS. Or right click the VS icon in task bar and click Visual Studio 2013. It is not a limitation for Community Edition. You can open any number of instances by this way.