# In Visual Studio 2015, is it possible to open two solutions in the same IDE process?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2015, I would like to find references in two solutions. Is it possible to open two solutions at the same time in the same IDE process, or should I create a different IDE process to open a different solution.

In a IDE process, if I have opened a solution, and I try to open a second solution, it looks like the IDE will close the first solution and open the second solution. 
So I am guessing it is not allowed to open two solutions in the same IDE process.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes One instance Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/4079330/1481690

Comment: Create a new solution and add all projects from both initial solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, only one solution per instance. A solution can have multiple projects, however, only one solution can be open at a time.  You will have to open two instances of Visual Studio.