# How to open Visual Studio Solution File from the Command Prompt

Tags: windows, visual-studio, command-line, command-prompt

Today I was in the Windows Command Prompt after doing a `git clone https://...MySolution.git` and wanted to open the **.sln** (i.e., solution file) from the new directory of the cloned repo.

What is the command to open this new solution in Visual Studio? Suppose the relative path is `/MySolution/MySolution.sln`

Comment: "....unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming"..... Did I miss something or is Visual Studio used for writing poetry nowadays? I nominated this question for reopen!

Comment: If you have mutliple versions of Visual Studio installed and want to open the solution file using a specific version of VS then you can pass the solution path directly to the devenv.exe: _"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" "D:\some\path\myapp.sln"_

Answer (score 103, accepted):

If you haven't done `cd MySolution` but are still in the directory from which you did the `git clone` just type

`start MySolution/MySolution.sln` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This will open whatever version of Visual Studio you currently have set to open with `.sln` files in Windows.

Comment: Also, ```start "vs exe path" "solution path"``` does not require changing directories as a pre-requisite e.g. ```start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" "C:\Code\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.sln"```

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you can also do directly `\MySolution\MySolution.sln` or `.\MySolution\MySolution.sln` and the solution will be opened.

I've been using it in CMD and Powershell with no problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO Cristian. Yeah, on PowerShell the `Tab` autocomplete works well for these, so good times. As you said they work on CMD as well but the `Tab` Autocomplete doesn't work for the second half, i.e.  `\MyS` + `Tab` doesn't resolve to `\MySolution.sln`, but it does when when you prefix `start ...`. CMD just isn't smart enough :)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using PowerShell, you should try [WhatsNew](https://github.com/refactorsaurusrex/whats-new#open-visual-studio-solutions-from-the-command-line). Once installed, you can just type `sln` to open the solution file in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in some of the answers, you can directly launch sln-files from the command line, i.e.

`MySolution\MySolution.sln`

The fastest way to start a solution is to take advantage of the tab-completion. Note that this only works if you have only one solution-file in the folder.

If you are in the solution folder:

`*sln`<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>

If you are not in the solution folder:

`MySolution\*sln`<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>

Or depending on your location you can tab-complete the solution folder as well:

`MySol`<kbd>tab</kbd>`\*sln`<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>

This works in **PowerShell** as well with the following differences:

- the backslash is automatically inserted upon doing tab-completion on a folder
- you can use backslash or slash to mark a folder path